# some view in fragment not animated with transition

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I want to implement a Fragment toggle animation by using setEnterTransition method.

the Fragment view is like this:

```
    <RelativeLayout
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/id_rl_root">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_stub_animation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#ccffee"
        android:layout_height="30dp">
    </View>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/index_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

views in index Containers are dynamically generated. and the page like this
[image]

and I add the enterTransition in BaseFragment.onCreate method.

```
    val inflater = TransitionInflater.from(requireContext())
    enterTransition = inflater.inflateTransition(R.transition.slide_right)
```

When I enter the fragment, only the view_stub_animation do the animate, while the index_container just came straight out.

I don't want to use the setCustomAnimate because when I do the animate, page presentation is not smooth enough.

Crazy. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I realized that if I add a background color to the Index_Container, I can animate it, which feels like a transition feature? maybe...